# Armature issues and deforming

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

So, I've made a character out of multiple different parts that I've mixed and matched to a point where I'm satisfied.

However, I'm having issues with the armature and deformation as shown here

[image]

Got about 25 hours in blender by now, so still new, and can't really figure out the weight paint stuff.

Looked at another thread and someone talked about going into *Edit Mode* and messing with the vertex, but I couldn't figure that out either.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! What have you all tried so far? Are you familiar with Weight Paint Mode yet? Do you know anything about vertex groups?

Comment: I've tried to separate the coat into 2 pieces, the lower being parented to 1 bone, but that looked really stupid when posing. Tried with weight paint, but that didn't get me any where. I know nothing about vertex groups

Comment: I was thinking, couldn't I add bones bones to the coat? Would that stop the leg bones from interfering with the coat part?

Comment: That is what I would suggest. I'm assuming you want the coat to be able to move separately from the leg, and that would be a good way to do it.

Comment: How should I go about parenting it, just parent it to the hipbone?

Comment: Yes. In edit mode on your armature create a chain of bones for each section of the coat and parent each of those chains to whatever bone on the armature they should be attached to.

Comment: Here is a great tutorial as well on how to create rigs and how weight painting and vertex groups work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU He does a much better job than I could do here. If you have any questions about the process though feel free to start a question and let me know and I can help you out.

Comment: How can I mark this question as answered?